# I have an old piece of hardware I want to run Ubuntu, can I reformat using the 13.04 download on my Dell 700m?

Tags: 13.04, dell, laptop, inspiron

I recently recovered my Dell Inspiron 700m from my collection of old hardware. I have a ton of old files and programs on it, none of which I need. I want to install ubuntu and make it a running machine again. Can I replace the windows operating system and reformat with the new ubuntu 13.04 download?

Comment: Yes, you can, and welcome to askubuntu. [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) is, arguably, a better option for an old machine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but according to the specs you have on your machine I'd recommend to use Lubuntu. Also, it'd be wise to increase the RAM to, at least, 1GB.

Comment: Is increasing the RAM a necessary component for both OS? Thank you guys, this is going to help

Comment: The more RAM you get, the better performance you'll get. For Ubuntu you'll need at least 2GB for good performance and for Lubuntu you need at least 1GB for good performance (I'd recommend 2GB for a system like yours).

Comment: I forgot tell you to check the RAM maximum limit that your machine allows.

Comment: I'm making steps to MAX out my RAM, is there any other hardware that this Dell 700m laptop could use? (new processor, wireless card, etc.?)

Comment: I am not quite sure about changing the processor but for the wireless adapter you can use a USB dongle of the latest generation in order to increase the wireless speed.